# View's getWindowToken() is null after windowManager.addView()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-windowmanager, android-window

I have added the view by using `WindowManager` like this:

`windowManager.addView(view, view.getViewParams());`

Before and after this line I check `view.getWindowToken()` and it is always `null`.

Could you explain why `view.getWindowToken()` is `null` and when it becomes not `null`?

Comment: Check on the next frame.

Comment: And how can I do this? @azizbekian

Comment: `view.post(new Runnable() { public void run() { view.getWindowToken(); } })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform `windowManager.addView(...)` the view does **not** immediately get attached to window. Rather you are posting an action, that will take place some time later.

In order to wait enough so that above mentioned *"some time"* passes, you can post an action to the view:

```
    view.post(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() { 
            // now view is attached to window
            view.getWindowToken(); 
        } 
    });
```